# silverPDF - PDF Sharp Silverlight Library [TypeInitialization_Type] Arguments: PdfSharp.PSSR

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I get this error when creating a PDF from Silverlight with SilverPDF.

> [TypeInitialization_Type]  Arguments:
>   PdfSharp.PSSR

Additional Info in the Stack Trace:

> [MissingManifestResource_NoNeutralAsm]
>   Arguments:
>   PdfSharp.Resources.Messages.resources,silverPDF

Any ideas what this is?  What is the PdfSharp.PSSR class?

Answer (score 1):

PSSR contains the PDFsharp string resources, allowing localized error messages.

SilverPDF is a port of PDFsharp for Silverlight. Maybe they made something wrong with the resources of PSSR, so instead of a readable error message you now get an exception.